# SVG wave not stretching to 100% width in Safari

Tags: html, css, svg

My SVG isn't scaling to 100% width in Safari like it is in IE, Chrome, and Firefox. I tried a lot but can't get my SVG to stretch across to 100% width like in all the other browsers. I am using React.

```css
.hero-svg {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

svg {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div className="hero-svg">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
        <path fill="#3dd0f2" fillOpacity="1" d="M0,128L80,117.3C160,107,320,85,480,117.3C640,149,800,235,960,229.3C1120,224,1280,128,1360,80L1440,32L1440,0L1360,0C1280,0,1120,0,960,0C800,0,640,0,480,0C320,0,160,0,80,0L0,0Z"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

I tried using `preserveAspectRatio = "none"` but it doesn't change much.

Here is a screenshot of Chrome and then Safari:

## Chrome:

[image]

## Safari:

[image]

Comment: It stretches OK on my iPad with Safari (IOS 14).

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you mean by _svg isn't scaling to 100% width in Safari_. I've just checked it in Safar v14 and it seems to be fine.

Comment: You are using `className`. Do you use react?

Comment: Yes i am using react and i just uploaded a screenshot

Comment: z-index won't work without position, try adding svg namespaces and remove display:flex

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. This worked:

```
<div className="hero-svg">
    <svg  viewBox="0 0 1440 320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path fill="#f0f0f0" fillOpacity="1" d="M0,32L80,32C160,32,320,32,480,37.3C640,43,800,53,960,80C1120,107,1280,149,1360,170.7L1440,192L1440,0L1360,0C1280,0,1120,0,960,0C800,0,640,0,480,0C320,0,160,0,80,0L0,0Z"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

css:

```
.hero-svg{
  display: flex; 
  width: 100%;

  svg{
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
```